# asp.net core infinite loading issue with IIS as proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

I cannot seem to get an ASP.NET CORE 3.1 API application to run as a sub-application within IIS **In Process** beneath a parent site.

The issue:

- The page keeps spinning (trying to load) when you browse to it.
- No errors are returned.  No errors logged in the "logs" folder (stdoutLogEnabled=true)
- No errors in Event Log

**NOTE: This application runs fine locally using Visual Studio with IISExpress**

Server info:

- Windows Server 2019
- Asp.NET Core 3.1.2 Hosting Bundle

IIS Parent site "www" setup:

- .NET Framework 4.x
- Has it's own Application Pool (v4.0  / Integrated)

IIS sub-application called "api" (child application of "www"):

- ASP.NET Core 3.1
- Has it's own Application pool (No Managed Code / Integrated / Enabled 32-Bit Applications = False)
- Unique `IIS AppPool\user` does have permissions to the file system directory

Web.Config (set to InProcess)

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\lib.api.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseIIS();
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Can you help find / produce error messages so I can troubleshoot this?
2. Do you know how to keep this from spinning (infinite loading) when browsing to
   or using Postman `Get` request?

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could try to use fail request tracing to troubleshoot the issue, By using this tool, you could find the which module cause the inifinite loading. More details about how to use it, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing).

Comment: Thanks, @BrandoZhang - I tried this already with no luck.  This seems so strange.  If I do a self-contained (or framework dependent) publish it still 'spins' when using IIS proxy.  However, if I use command line and execute the executable the api loads flawlessly.  Hmm

Comment: Could you please post the related config or setting about how you set the IIS proxy?